# Guide for replacing Enterprise Lib 4.1 Caching with Azure Caching

Tags: azure, enterprise-library, distributed-caching

We have a current implementation of caching which uses Enterprise Library 4.1 Caching Block. Currently the website is hosted on premise.

But soon, this web site will be hosted in Azure which doesn't support sticky session. As a result we need to refactor the caching pattern and replace with azure dedicated caching.

I've not used azure caching before but read few articles on MSDN. I've not seen guide on how to replace Ent. Lib caching with Azure caching.

Could someone please help me what are the steps needed to replace the enterprise lib caching with Azure dedicated caching.

Comment: Could you not use the entlib azure integration pack http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680918(v=pandp.50).aspx